# How to rank two values based on the following criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have the following two columns, Benefit and Cost scoring results, each of which are out of a hundred.

I want to be able to order each row based on its ranking compared to each of the other row based on it Cost benefit scoring.

Where the higher the benefit and the lower the cost row is ranked higher and the lower the benefit and the higher the cost score row is ranked lower.

**Must have:** Higher benefit, Low Cost
**Should Have:** Higher benefit, High Cost
**Could Have:** Low Benefit, High Cost
**Wont Have:** Low Benefit, Low Cost

```
Name    B   C    Placement
Foo1   34  50   Could have
Foo2   20  55   Wont Have
Foo3   70  88   Should Have
Foo4   12  46   Wont Have
Foo5   80  52   Should Have
Foo6   31  32   Could Have
Foo7   43  10   Could have
Foo8   1   99   Wont Have
```

I have already assigned the placement order based on the following formula:

```
=IF((AND(B4>=50, C4>=50)), "Should Have", IF((AND(B4<=50, C4<=50)), "Could Have", IF((AND(B4>=50, C4<=50)), "Must Have", IF((AND(B4<=50, C4>=50)),"Wont Have", "Fail"))))
```

Expected Output would be the following,

Must have: Higher benefit, Low Cost
Should Have: Higher benefit, High Cost
Could Have: Low Benefit, High Cost
Wont Have: Low Benefit, Low Cost

```
Name    B   C    Order
Foo5    80  52   Should Have
Foo3    70  88   Should Have
Foo7    43  10   Could Have
Foo6    31  32   Could Have
Foo1    34  50   Could Have
Foo2    20  55   Wont Have
Foo4    12  46   Wont Have
Foo8    1   99   Wont Have
```

As you can see, the higher the Benefit and the lower the cost, ranks up higher.

Can this be done without VBA code?, is there a formula that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add a column of your expected output ranking?

Comment: @ScottCraner have added the expected output, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: "This" needs to be defined if someone is going to help. e.g. why is 70-88 rated better than 43-10? 31-32 better than 34-50? 43-10 might be the best choice based on budget etc.

Comment: So priority is to B?  Just sort the data with priority on B then secondary on C.

Comment: @ScottCraner Updated the question further to hopefully make it clearer - Thanks and sorry for the confusion, havent posted a question in a long time here

Comment: Since you've added another column, which seems to be the one you really want to sort on, why not sort with priority on Column D, then secondary on B and finally on C?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks mate, that did the trick, I was wanting something more automated as the user enters a new entry, it automatically sorts - but that may be a new question?

Comment: Sorting automatically definitely requires vba, which would make your question off-topic. You can ask specific questions about VBA here (I made this progress but stuck with next step...) instead of asking for entire solution.

Comment: Hi, @IAML I noticed in your "placement order" if statement.. an entry will have two possible outcome if either one of the cost or benefit is equal to 50. Since this is your final sorting criteria.. please update the "placement order" if statement with the one that won't 'clash' (overlapping conditions) to proceed.. (  :